# No replacement of temporary labels by chemnum in a ChemDraw eps on Mac

Tags: pdftex, mactex, eps, auto-pst-pdf, chemnum

I tried to replace the temporary labels TMP1, TMP2 and TMP3 in an .eps file made with ChemDraw v18 on Mac OSX Mojave using the `chemnum` package, so to get an automatic numbering of the compounds, but this did not work for me.

I tried different fonts for the label in the .eps file, or other options for `auto-pst-pdf` with no result.

The problem originally occurred on TexLive 2014 for Mac remains with Mac OSX 10.14 and TexLive 2019, compilation with `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex`(I use TexStudio).

For the following MWE with the following [eps file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k8ljxws03byz94h/test_cmpd_numbering.eps?dl=0).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[crop=off,runs=2]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{chemnum}
\usepackage{chemstyle}

\begin{document}

\begin{scheme}
    \replacecmpd[tag=TMP1]{cmpd:nucleophile1}
    \replacecmpd[tag=TMP2]{cmpd:nucleophile2}
    \replacecmpd[tag=TMP3]{cmpd:nucleophile3}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{test_cmpd_numbering.eps}
    \caption[test]{A test to make the numbering work}
\end{scheme}

\end{document}
```

The picture is inserted properly and the file `test_cmpd_numbering-pics.pdf` generated (that's a progress from previously), but the TMP1, TMP2 etc. labels are not replaced. Here is the [log file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6pyko7br2g6gp1a/test-wto-epstopdf.log?dl=0). It has got the error 'non-PDF special ignored!' which is often related to PdfLaTex difficulties on MacOSX.

Does anyone know why this code could make problems on Mac?

Comment: Your example works for me if I comment out `\usepackage{epstopdf}` (with the package it doesn't work) and compile with pdflatex (shell-escape enabled). The only tag that isn't replaced is in `then TMP1 in THF, -30\260` but this can't work: `psfrag` needs “a *single* word, composed of unaccented letters and numbers”. (`then TMP1 in THF, -30\260` is not a single word)

Comment: If I comment out `\usepackage{epstopdf}`, the aziridineopening-converted-to.pdf file is not created, hence an empty white space is included [instead of the picture](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13760766/test-wto-epstopdf.pdf). Curiously I get no warning or error message. I tested in a terminal if epstopdf works for himself - it seems fine and if I start it manually in the terminal, the ...-converted-to.pdf file is created correctly.

Comment: @SimonN. But `auto-pst-pdf` should *also* create a `...-pics.pdf`. (provided you're compiling with shell-escape enabled)

Comment: If I comment out `\usepackage{eps-to-pdf}` from the top MWE and compile with `--shell-escape`, the `...-pics.pdf` file is created, but it has no content. If I open this `...-pics.pdf`-file with a visualization program such as Preview or AdobeReader, I see only a small white quadrangle. And the aziridineopening-converted-to.pdf file is not created. Here the [log file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13760766/test-wto-epstopdf.log)

Comment: The error message for the previous comment is:
Error: /undefined in obj Operand stack: 2 0 Execution stack: %interp_exit .runexec2 --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 2 %stopped_push 
***(...)***
-- Current allocation mode is local Last OS error: Invalid argument Current file position is 132440 GPL Ghostscript 9.10: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

Comment: If I look at the .log-file, I can see line 956-957: `Preview: Fontsize 12pt
Preview: PDFoutput 1`. Could it be that somehow, the Mac Preview-Programm, which is often used to convert .eps to .pdf, interferes with the process? Or am I totally misleaded?

Comment: @clemens with the new install of the 2019 TexLive for Mac distribution the ...-pics.pdf is generated properly. However the TMP1 etc labels are not replaced. Should they already be included in the ...-pics.pdf file? I have edited the question with a new MWE with the correct files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there were 2 problems associated with this.

1. The PATH in TexStudio needed to be changed. This is a similar issue as [.eps files and pdflatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273344/eps-files-and-pdflatex) and reconfiguring texstudio as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270899/reconfiguring-texstudio-after-upgrade-to-os-x-el-capitan) solved it, here is a picture to clarify:
   [image: TexStudio change PATH]
2. ChemDraw 18 on Mac does not generate the .eps file properly, ie defining the text correctly. This issue is known and explained in more detail in [Chemdraw 16 for Mac OSX not working with psfrag and label replacing/autonumbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315793/chemdraw-16-for-mac-osx-not-working-with-psfrag-and-label-replacing-autonumberin?rq=1)
   My solution was to generate the .eps file on a Windows computer running ChemDraw 16...

The combination of both solved the problem for the above MWE. I have edited the above question to reflect more the nature of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is (independently of the Chemdraw Version: I used v16.0.0 and v22.0.0) because Chemdraw on MacOS has a bug when creating an .eps File so the string doesn't appear on a text Editor (a.k.a.: Ghostscript). The solution I found was:

1. Save the cropped File as a PDF (uncheck the Box: 'Break into pages'[v.22.0.0]. I didn't Found that Option on v.16.0 ).
2. Then convert the File.pdf to File.eps with a converter.
3. (optional) Open the .eps File with a text Editor and you will find the Script with the temporary marker (example.: TMP1).

I use personally Texmaker as a compiler so if you go to preferences, under the section 'Commands' paste this:
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex

Also compile the File with: PDF Latex to  View PDF and then compile it again with Quick Build to View PDF .

Here is my LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[scaled=0.92]{helvet}
    \renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{titleps}
\usepackage{graphicx,auto-pst-pdf}
\renewcommand*\sectionformat{\thesection\autodot\hspace{1cm}}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,total={7in,10in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{titleps}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ghsystem}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{chemstyle}
\usepackage{chemscheme}
\usepackage{chemschemex}
\usepackage{chemnum}



\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}


\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[3][]
{
  colframe = #2!50,
  colback  = #2!0,
  coltitle = #2!20!black,  
  title    = {#3},
  #1,
}

\newpagestyle{ruled}

{\sethead{}{}{ \sectiontitle}\headrule 
\setfoot{}{\thepage}{}\footrule}
\pagestyle{ruled}




\begin{document}
\section{TEST}


 \begin{scheme}[H]
   \replacecmpd{CompoundX}
     \replacecmpd{CompoundY}
      \centering
       \includegraphics[scale=1]{Filename.eps}
       \caption{Random Stuff you want to write here}
       \label{Your Label}
 \end{scheme}
 
Hier \cmpd{CompoundX} und \cmpd{CompundY}.
\end{document}
```

Additional Info: I use macOS Catalina v.10.15.7. My texmaker version is: 5.1.3.