# TexMaker (and TexShop) not working after installation of El Capitan

Tags: errors, mactex, texshop, mac

After having updated to Mac OS X El Capitan (10.11), I'm no more able to compile using either TexMaker or TexShop. This is the message I get from TexShop

"/usr/texbin/pdflatex does not exist. TeXShop is  a front end for TeX, but you also need a TeX distribution. Perhaps such a distribution was not installed or was removed during a system upgrade. If so, go to http://www.tug.org/mactex/ and follow the instructions to (re)install MacTeX. A less likely possibility is that a tool path is incorrectly configured in TeXShop preferences. This can happen if you are using the macports or fink distributions."

I tried to change the path in Preferences-Engine, as many suggested. Yet, it doesn't work either. Any help?

Comment: You may have to reconfigure the folder structure referenced by TeXmaker. Related: [Reconfiguring TexStudio after upgrade to OS X El Capitan](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/270899/5764)

Comment: You must update Texshop.

Comment: Welcome! See [this page](https://www.tug.org/mactex/elcapitan.html).

Comment: @MartinSchröder: I fail to see how this is a duplicate in the sense that this is asking about TeXShop, and the "existing answer" tells what to do for TeXStudio. The answers in this question and the "existing answer" do not help a TeXShop user at all. The GUIs are completely different.

Answer (score 14):

I just solved it. You just need to change the path of the files for the command according to the new organization in El Captain. I posted a screenshot. It works for me!

Hope this helps!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Thank you! that's exactly right! In TexShop I had to do the same too. Add `/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/universal-darwin/` to the path settings in the Engine tab.

Comment: I changed my settings according to the post after upgrading to El Capitan. I can compile .tex now, but cannot use R Sweave. Can someone help? Thanks very much! I get this message in TexMaker: Error : could not start the command : R CMD Sweave "text".Rnw...