# TeXMaker doesn't work after upgrade to OS X El Capitan

Tags: texmaker, mac

I have now read a lot of guides and stuff about, why TeXMaker won't work.

It should work, but it won't - and I therefore hope, that some of you can help me. I have changed the `usr/texbin` to `/library/TeX/texbin/` EVERYWHERE.

Here is two updated photos of my preferences => "Commands" and "Quick Build". I hope someone can help me:

[image]

[image]

Is it necessary to download and install the new MacTeX-2015-packages?

I really hate this - it still says the following:

[image]

Comment: Have you seen question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271078/texmaker-and-texshop-not-working-after-installation-of-el-capitan? Possible duplicate?

Comment: Is there any error message you can show us?

Comment: @Johannes_B see the updated edit. I don't know what happen.

Comment: Seems this has nothing to do with *el capitan*. Can you show us a minimal working example of the code that generates the messages?

Comment: Not the problem, but I don't think that you should have changed the path for `gs`. Was that path really `/usr/texbin/local/bin/gs` before? I suspect it was `/usr/local/bin/gs`. If so, it should stay `/usr/local/bin/gs`. Similarly for anything else which wasn't in `/usr/texbin` to begin with.

Comment: @cfr I have now tried- but it still won't work

Comment: Yes. You need to install Mac TeX 2015.

Comment: I have tried. I have also tried to change all folders name. I have tried to switch it to /Library/TeXShop/bin/ - without luck. It still says (see edit)

Comment: Looking at the error messages, this cannot be a problem of setting up a tex-distribution on a mac.  This is an issue of LaTeX-coding. Without more details on that side, there is no point in investigating any further, sorry.

Comment: I think I have found the problem. I am using MinionPro as font. Do you know what is wrong by using that?

Comment: Do you have the (commenrcial) font installed? Try commenting out the line, there are plenty of other fonts available.

Comment: I download MinionPro from CRAN and after that I ran "/scripts/makeall MinionPro", and "/scripts/install" and finally "sudo updmap-sys --enable Map=MinionPro.map". Would you suggest me to ran this again?

Comment: Don't know what has to be done, i don't have the font, it is too expensive. Why can you download it from CRAN?

Comment: @Johannes_B What's CRAN? Probably this should say CTAN? If so, then I take it that the OP has downloaded the package from there, not bothered to read the instructions, run the script and ignored the errors. Since the package doesn't include the fonts, it obviously won't work. However, that does not seem to be the problem causing the errors shown in the question.

Comment: @cfr Unlear from my point of view. https://cran.r-project.org/

Comment: @Johannes_B Ah. Yes. I didn't know that. Seems unlikely they'd have MinionPro, but who knows? Definitely altogether unclear.

Comment: Sorry. I mean CTAN. See this: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/minionpro/

Comment: Do you have the fonts? The LaTeX-package does not include the fonts. They are commercial and quite expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem and suggest you locate the files yourself.

My files, for example, are located in `Library/TeX/Root/bin/x86_64-darwin/`
and I therefore replaced `usr/texbin/` with `Library/TeX/Root/bin/x86_64-darwin/` everywhere instead of `library/TeX/texbin/`.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I narrowed it down to the fact, that ghostscript doesn't work. Therefore, converting an EPS-File into PS works, but PS to PDF doesn't. I hope that someone can help me figure this out. I tried to install Ghostscript again, but the installer won't let me change the directory to anything else than `/usr/local` and since this directory is restricted since El Capitan, I don't see any way to fix this :(
@Gavin: there is no `gs` (= GhostScript) in that folder, thats the problem!

Comment: `/usr/local` is ***not*** restricted. `/usr` and `/usr/<anything-but-local` is.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of people explained that the way to go is replace the path with the one in your computer. My problem was that I didn't know how to find the path in the first place. What I did was I opened the terminal and looked for a specific file, for example `pdflatex`. To do so I typed:

```
mdfind pdflatex
```

This will display the path of all files containing `pdflatex` in their name. From there it was (at least for me) kind of arbitrary to decide which was the actual path. I found one including the words `darwin` and `usr/local` and used that one, and it worked. More specifically the path for my computer was

```
/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-darwin/
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! In the Linux world, there is `which`, which shows the full path of executables. Maybe, it also works in OS/X.

Comment: Thank you @HeikoOberdiek! which actually works better :)

Answer (score 0):

here's my solution, different w.r.t. those before: [image]