# TeXMaker, El Capitan - MinionPro?

Tags: fonts, texmaker, minionpro

I am normally using MinionPro. MinionPro won't work after I updated to El Capitan. Can someone help?

My preamble look like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,fleqn,oneside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fixltx2e} 
\usepackage{layout} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[lf]{MinionPro}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{icomma}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,bm,mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,left=2.0cm,right=2.0cm]{geometry}
%%%boks
\usepackage{xcolor}    
\usepackage{ntheorem}  
\usepackage{mdframed}  
\usepackage{capt-of}
\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\theoremheaderfont{\bf}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xcolor}    
\usepackage{ntheorem}  
\usepackage{mdframed}  
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\theoremheaderfont{\bf}
\newmdtheoremenv[linecolor=black,leftmargin=99,rightmargin=99,backgroundcolor=gray!12,innertopmargin=5pt,ntheorem]{myprop}{\begin{large} \hspace{2cm}\end{large}} 
%%&margin

\usepackage{paperandpencil}

\begin{document}

Hello

\end{document}
```

Comment: You figured out it is a problem wit`h minionpro` as can also be seen in [TeXMaker doesn't work after upgrade to OS X El Capitan](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/271493). Why are you still loading all the other packages in the question? Are they needed to reproduce the behaviour?

Comment: Why are you loading packages multiple times? Why are you using deprecated font-switches? What is the definition of `myprop` supposed to do? Is this really the same question as the other one? Because the error there doesn't seem to have anything to do with El Capitain.