# Error with "/usr/texbin/pdflatex

Tags: errors, compiling, mac

TexMaker refuse to compile with Error : could not start the command : "/usr/texbin/pdflatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode

I have read that same happened after installation of El Capitan, but I have installed the last Mac update Sierra. I have tried to reinstall MacTex, but it didn't help.

In the settings it is offering me to choose between version 2013 and 2016 but I can't choose neither of them, it is failing with "Setting up the /usr/texbin link"

[image]

Please help. 
Nelya

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be related to the restrictions on the /usr directory in El Capitan and Sierra: see [here](http://tug.org/mactex/sierra.html). I guess that removing completely TeX Live from your system and installing a fresh 2016 copy should fix the issue with the directory.

Comment: Reinstall did not help, but I just tried to change the path of the files for the command as explained here and it helped. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271078/texmaker-and-texshop-not-working-after-installation-of-el-capitan?rq=1