# TexStudio 2015 error

Tags: texstudio, mac

I have just updated my Mac to El Capitan. I also updated my MacTex to the newest MacTex 2015 by downloading and installing it. I also updated my TexStudio to TeXstudio 2.10.2 (the latest version). Now, when I try to compile my previously well-working `.tex` files I get this:

> Error: Could not start the command: /usr/texbin/pdflatex -synctex=1
>   -interaction=nonstopmode

On TexShop which comes as part of MacTex package my files open and compile just fine. Please, I really am used to TexStudio, can anyone tell me what, how should I configure my TexStudio so it can work with MacTex, El Capitan...?

Comment: Please look at all the other El Capitan questions currently on the site. Apple have disallowed anyone but apple to write on /usr so /usr/texbin will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to [Herbert Schulz's instruction](https://tug.org/mactex/UpdatingForElCapitan.pdf) or this question ["Reconfiguring TexStudio after upgrade to OS X El Capitan"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270899/reconfiguring-texstudio-after-upgrade-to-os-x-el-capitan) about how to modify TeXstudio's command configuration after upgrading to OS X El Capitan.

Answer (score 1):

There is a change in the way OS X El Capitan allows apps to access system folders, all you have to do is open Settings and change every instance of **/usr/texbin/** to **Library/TeX/texbin/**. This is under the *Commands* tab.

Edit: Clarified with screenshot

[image: Screenshot of TexStudio]