# .eps files and pdflatex

Tags: texstudio, eps, epstopdf

I am trying to include an `.eps` figure in a document and build with pdflatex:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{figure}    
\end{document}
```

The error I get is:

```
sh: epstopdf: command not found

Package pdftex.def Error: File `figure-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found. \includegraphics{figure}
```

Adding `-shell-escape` as mentioned in previous posts does not solve the issue. I have reinstalled `epstopdf` with TeX Live. I am using TeXstudio 2.10.2 on Mac OS X 10.10.5.

Edit:

Apparently, this is an editor-related issue since everything works fine if called from command line.

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) We need to know what LaTeX installation you are using. You mention TeX Live, which version? And since you are on Mac, why not MacTeX?

Comment: @daleif Thanks. I have TeX Live version 1.23. I do not really have a justification for not using MacTeX except for my lack of experience. I have just downloaded and installed the 2015 distribution, but I still cannot compile the example above.

Comment: Erh, What exactly is version 1.23? The current TeX Live is version 2015.

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to Tex Live Utility.

Comment: `sh: epstopdf: command not found` doesn't sound good. What happens if you call `epstopdf --help` in a command line?

Comment: I get the manual page:
`epstopdf ($Id: epstopdf.pl 36129 2015-01-24 00:30:11Z karl $) 2.23
Usage: epstopdf [OPTION]... [EPSFILE]

Convert EPS to PDF (or other formats), by default using Ghostscript.` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With TeXLive 2015, `eps` files should be converted to `pdf` automatically when using pdflatex. There is no need to load the `epstopdf` package. The error you are getting suggests that the system is looking for the `epstopdf` script in the wrong place. According to [the user manual](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION02), there are various settings that TeXStudio uses when looking for commands of this type. If there is a setting for `epstopdf`, then do

```
which epstopdf
```

in the terminal and paste the result in its place. Failing this, compile the following document with shell escape enabled:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\immediate\write18{echo $PATH > tmp1}
\immediate\write18{which epstopdf > tmp2} 
\end{document}
```

(Note that this will destroy any existing files called `tmp1` and `tmp2` in the current directory.) Then edit your question by adding the contents of the files `tmp1` and `tmp2`.

**EDIT**

Integrated development environments are the work of Satan. I just downloaded TeXStudio and reproduced exactly the same problem. Using the code above, I determined that it is searching for epstopdf in a nonexistent TeXLive2012 directory. In the file

```
~/.config/texstudio/texstudio.ini
```

I found the following:

```
Tools\Search%20Paths=/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-darwin
```

I can't find an option to change this from within TeXStudio (someone else who knows the software better than me may know how to do it). I tried editing the file, since I think it should be

```
Tools\Search%20Paths=/usr/texbin
```

but when I restarted TeXStudio the `.ini` file changed back automatically. Here is a workaround (which requires admin privileges). In the terminal:

```
sudo tsch
```

and enter your password to make yourself root. Now create the missing directory as follows:

```
cd /usr/local/texlive
mkdir 2012
cd 2012
mkdir bin
cd bin
mkdir x86_64-darwin
cd x86_64-darwin
```

Finally, create a symbolic link to the real location of `epstopdf`:

```
ln -s `which epstopdf` ./epstopdf
```

Now when TeXStudio looks for epstopdf it will find the symbolic link leading to the proper location.

Comment: Sorry for not editing the question, but I do not really know what each of these paths are and what the context is so I am leaving the answer here. Compiling the above file in TeXstudio gives: tmp1: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin :/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-darwin` and an empty file for tmp2. Compiling from terminal gives tmp1: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin` and tmp2: `/Library/TeX/texbin/epstopdf`.

Comment: @Smurf --- see edit.

Answer (score 3):

For any Linux user arriving here with the same problem, it might be that you did not install the package `texlive-font-utils`.

Simply:

```
sudo apt install texlive-font-utils
```

Comment: This simply solves the error on TexStudio

Answer (score 0):

You can basically remove the `\usepackage{epstopdf}` and just leave the code as it is.

So you will have:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{figure}    
\end{document}
```

Of course you have to be sure that the file `figure.eps` is in the same folder of the .tex file you are trying to compile.

You need to use LaTex. I actually use : PdfLaTex. It works fine.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Perhaps you should mention that it's necessary to use `latex` then

Comment: `figure.eps` is in the same folder as the `.tex` file I am trying to compile. If I do not include `epstopdf` and use `latex`, the document compiles, but the figure is still not converted to `.pdf`, i.e. there is no file `figure-eps-converted-to.pdf` in the folder.

Comment: Smurf: As long as you don't have `epstopdf` as script available, usage of `epstopdf` package is quite useless and there will be no `...converted-to.pdf` file at all

Comment: @ChristianHupfer The issue is that I believe that I do have `epstopdf` installed, but `sh: epstopdf: command not found` still happens.

Comment: @Smurf: Try to call from the command line: `pdflatex --shell-escape foo.tex`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, that worked, thanks a lot. Can you guess what the matter is with TeXstudio then? The command is specified as `/usr/texbin/pdflatex -shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex `

Comment: @Smurf: I never used TeXStudio, TexMaker, etc and all those `editors`. Compiling from command line works 'always'.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to @Ian Thompson

I meet the same problem. This solution is to change the search path.

Open option->configure->tick the `Show Advanced Options`, then in `Build` setting, you can find `Build Options`.

This last line in `Build Options` is `Commands($PATH)`, type `/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux`(depend on your texstudio edition and os)

Now texstudio can find `epstopdf` automatically

Comment: I don't know why someone votes down my answer. I solve my problem through this method : )

Comment: Hi, and excuse me for this comment. It is my opinion: you try to explain better your answer, with images, or link, or screenshot, or with a code. :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano I'm lazy